# protractor executeScript doesnot run the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, protractor

Im trying to post a api using for my registration page and i have used $HTTP request to post data

```
 it('login page to patient dashboard with existing email and password', function() {
        console.log('entering login page')    
        browser.get('http://localhost:9000/login.html');
        browser.executeScript(function(callback) {
            var $http;
            $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");
            console.log('http request')
            return $http({
                url: "http://int.eclinic247.com/reg/create-patient",
                method: "post",
                data: {"firstName":"jya","lastName":"raq"},
                dataType: "json"
            }).success(function() {
                return callback([true]);
                console.log('done')
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                return callback([false, data, status]);
                 console.log('oops not done!!!!')
            });
        })
    element(by.model(Objects.locators.passwordBox)).sendKeys(Objects.login.password);
```

I see that the executeScript block doesnot run and there are no errors too...and the test case passes

Is this the way to post a http request using protractor...Please suggest me the proper to post a data to back-end directly

Any help is much appreciated...Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understand your use case, but this seems like an anti-pattern. If you need to create a user, why not talk directly to your database/orm, or make an HTTP request to your API in a `beforeEach`. That way the client doesn't have to worry about creating data.

Comment: @NickTomlin...can you please provide a example of doing so.......This could be really helpfull.......Thanks for your reply

Comment: You would either use a node HTTP module (like the built in `http` or [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)) to make a POST request in your test file (with the same parameters as the XHR you are making in your client code). If you are not familiar with `beforeEach` you should read the jasmine documentation

Comment: @NickTomlin ...Thanks for your help...can i just use ..........request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}}).....in beforeEach .....Is this the correct way?

Comment: It depends on what your endpoint wants. Form is wrong if you need to post JSON (which it seems like you do). You should review the request docs, but `reqeust.post({body: {foo: 'bar'}, json: true})` should work